# Is there any way to get the column names in any row for Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Spreadsheet Column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsYAp.jpg)

I have a spreadsheet in which I have data from Column A through BN, and I need the names of columns (A, B, C,..., Z, AA, AB,..., BL, BM, BN) in a row as shown in the picture.

Is there any formula which will give me the name of the column of the cell it is used in? (say the formula is typed in the cell C4 then it will return value C and if written in the cell AB4 then it will return value AB)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(address(row(),Column(),4),"\D+")
```

Comment: I tried and found this formulae:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(A1)),"$1",""),"$","")

Copy this formulae in A1 and then paste in any row and we will get column name (Alphabet) for that row